# How to make the query in Laravel (6) more faster and efficient?

Tags: laravel-6

I'm fetching a lot of data approximately 50,000 to 80,000 or more are being fetched.

```
$sqlmain = DB::table('lending_payments')
                ->select(
                    'lending_loandetails.clientid',
                    'lending_loandetails.coborrowerid',
                    'lending_loandetails.comaker1id',
                    'lending_loandetails.comaker2id',
                    'lending_loandetails.comaker3id',
                    'lending_loandetails.comaker4id',
                    'lending_loandetails.comaker5id'
                )
                ->join(DB::raw("(SELECT MAX(paymentid) as maxpaymentid
                    FROM lending_payments
                    WHERE lending_payments.paymentdate < '$cutoffdate'
                    GROUP BY lending_payments.pnid) as qry_b"), function ($join) {
                    $join->on('qry_b.maxpaymentid', '=', 'lending_payments.paymentid');
                })
                ->join('lending_loandetails', 'lending_loandetails.pnid', '=', 'lending_payments.pnid')
                ->where('lending_payments.loanbalance', '<>', 0)
                ->get();
            
            foreach ($sqlmain as $data) {
                $borrowers[$data->clientid] = 1;
                $coBorrowers[$data->coborrowerid] = 1;
                $coBorrowers[$data->comaker1id] = 1;
                $coBorrowers[$data->comaker2id] = 1;
                $coBorrowers[$data->comaker3id] = 1;
                $coBorrowers[$data->comaker4id] = 1;
                $coBorrowers[$data->comaker5id] = 1;
            }
```

That took 41 seconds to finish. And that's one of the three query needed to be executed.
(This was my first question, I don't even know if I'm right. haha)

I tried chunk but it doesn't fit the requirements.

Comment: Only select the columns you need. In your current query, you are selecting many columns from the table, but you only seem to use a few of them.